# .NET8 razor component InteractiveServer with Visual Studio

Tags: razor, .net-8.0

I am trying to incorporate a razor component example into my existing .NET8 project.
On the client side I have

@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode

. I think I have Program.cs set up OK.

Visual Studio will not accept

```
 <component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer"
            param-IncrementAmount="3" />
```

InteractiveServer as the RenderMode.  It will accept ServerPrerendered, but that does not give interactive updating by clicking the ClickMe button.

Looking around for doc and examples I find many that show the razor component (server) side of the code, but see practically nothing for the compatible client side coding.

Can someone provide a solution to get InteractiveServer working?

Comment: I created a new razor page. It will accept
<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode=InteractiveServer
           param-IncrementAmount="3" />
until  I add
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
.  Then InteractiveServer is not permitted.

Comment: Without taghelper, there is no display of the component.